# What is the difference betwen phase difference and crossover difference?

Tags: statistical-significance

I just read an article about a trial where subjects tried some treatments over time that says "The phase difference was significant, but the crossover difference was not significant." What is this statistical comparison method it is using?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a Crossover Design:

> A crossover design is a repeated measurements design such that each
>   experimental unit (patient) receives different treatments during the
>   different time periods, i.e., the patients cross over from one
>   treatment to another during the course of the trial. This is in
>   contrast to a parallel design in which patients are randomized to a
>   treatment and remain on that treatment throughout the duration of the
>   trial.

I found this in an [online course at PSU](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat509/book/export/html/123) that explains it well, though it doesn't mention "phase" -- it looks to me that they may instead use "periods":

> At a minimum, it always is recommended to invoke a design that is
>   uniform within periods because period effects are common. Period
>   effects can be due to:
>   1. increased patient comfort in later periods with trial processes; 
>   2. increased patient knowledge in later periods;
>   3.improvement in skill and technique of those researchers taking the measurements.